# Search image by textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I seek for solution which I need to search image at textbox. 
When value in TextBox same with image name, the picturebox will display that image. Because I have many picture in 1 folder. Can anyone help me pleaseee? Here is my current code:

```
if (textBoxEmplNo.Text == "TR0319")
{
     pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\may\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\tr0319.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the user can enter anything into that `TextBox` and, if there's a file with that name in a specific folder, you want to open that file in a `PictureBox`?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yes. U got it. That what I means. :)

Comment: @Miza the path where you are looking for image and image format(for example .png) are fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a variation that has a couple of advantages thay may or may not be beneficial to you:

```
var folderPath = @"C:\Users\may\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo";
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
var filePath = filePaths.FirstOrDefault(s => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s).Equals(textBox1.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

if (filePath != null)
{
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = filePath;
}
```

That allows your image files to have any extension and it also won't lock the file when it opens one.

Comment: Thanks for your respond! You make my day!

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
string imgFilePath = @"C:\Users\may\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\EV\photo\" + textBoxEmplNo.Text + ".jpg"
if(File.Exists(imgFilePath))
{
      pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgFilePath);
}
else
{
     // Display message that No such image found
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you make my day!

Comment: Do u mind if I ask some question. Why my gridview is not appears when I typing? or do u have any channel so that I can ask question directly to you?

Comment: @Miza: I don't have anything like that, Feel free to frame it as a question here so that you will get better answers and suggestions

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Because I still a newbie in programming and still in learning process. So, many question I want to ask. :)

Comment: can u help me solve the problem in this question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43749423/auto-suggest-on-gridview-when-typing-on-textbox)